# Don't know how to solve problems with database and room on android I already tried change dependencies but did not work

Tags: android, database, android-room, viewmodel

`

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.management.activities10, PID: 24535
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.management.activities10/com.management.activities10.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22 in com.management.activities10:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #22 in com.management.activities10:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3432)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3596)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2067)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:200)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7666)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22 in com.management.activities10:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #22 in com.management.activities10:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22 in com.management.activities10:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for com.management.activities10.database.ProjectsRoomDatabase. ProjectsRoomDatabase_Impl does not exist
        at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.kt:58)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.kt:1347)
        at com.management.activities10.database.ProjectsRoomDatabase.getDatabase(ProjectsRoomDatabase.java:54)
        at com.management.activities10.database.ProjectsRepository.<init>(ProjectsRepository.java:42)
        at com.management.activities10.ViewModel.CommonViewModel.init(CommonViewModel.java:89)
        at com.management.activities10.ui.Projects.Projects.onCreateView(Projects.java:52)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3104)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:524)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1424)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2968)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2879)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3129)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:394)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:260)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:142)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:136)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:248)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:227)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1075)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1003)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:967)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1129)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1090)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at com.management.activities10.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:49)
        at com.management.activities10.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:43)
        at com.management.activities10.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1321)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3405)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3596)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2067)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:200)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7666)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24535 SIG: 9
```

`

I tried add new dependecies but did not work. Also added dependencies from https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room but it gave me something like this
"A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method ksp() for arguments [androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
> "

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '1.7.0-1.0.6' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


ext {
    appCompatVersion = '1.3.0'
    constraintLayoutVersion = '2.0.4'
    coreTestingVersion = '2.1.0'
    lifecycleVersion = '2.3.1'
    materialVersion = '1.3.0'
    roomVersion = '2.3.0'
    // testing
    junitVersion = '4.13.2'
    espressoVersion = '3.1.0'
    androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.2'
}



plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-android'

}

android {
    namespace 'com.management.activities10'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.management.activities10"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}



dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    def room_version = "2.4.3"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    // To use Kotlin Symbol Processing (KSP)
   // ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // optional - RxJava2 support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"

    // optional - RxJava3 support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava3:$room_version"

    // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
    implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"

    // optional - Test helpers
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"

    // optional - Paging 3 Integration
    implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:2.5.0-beta01"


}
```

Comment: You are trying to use Kotlin Symbol Processing without properly including/applicating it.

Comment: Well how should I include it I add the kotlin plugin as mention in some articles

Comment: it looks like issue in XML file

Comment: when I comment the  mCommonViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(CommonViewModel.class);

Comment: in fragment it does work

Comment: First step would be adding your gradle files so it can be reviwed

Comment: Okey it is here

Comment: I commented the ksp and I am getting error like

Comment: protected void onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
                     ^
  attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public

Comment: and also  uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. in view model